# Highlight attribute name in product edit form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I need to highlight some divs with attribute names in product form in Magento2. Is there some way to do so? Or, at least, give me a hint where to look.[image: It has to look something like this]
I can't even find where attributes are loaded by fieldset. My guess is this is done in js somewhere. Solution would be something like adding a custom css class to all attributes that I want to be highlighted, but that's just my guess, and I don't know how to do that either, to be frank.

Comment: You can add your custom CSS for Backend and you can change styles of label. You can check this module.. https://github.com/KishanSavaliya/magehelper-magento2-overrite-backend-theme   I've override backend theme here and added custom css as well there.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to create a custom backend theme, then create an **_extend.less** file within that custom theme that adds the highlight styles to whichever field you want to highlight.

Here's info on creating a custom back-end theme: https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-add-magento-2-admin-theme/

And the custom styles would go in a file at app/design/adminhtml/**[YOURVENDORNAME]/[YOURTHEMENAME]**/web/css/source/_extend.less

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to add a class that you can reference in your less file for each attribute you want to highlight, so you'd likely have to do it manually (e.g):

div[data-index="special_price"] span {
    background: yellow;
}